# tomcat not starting

Tags: java, tomcat, jasperserver

suddenly for some reason tomcat server is not runnin/starting/stopping.

below is the result I get when i run the startup command,

```
  C:\Program Files\jasperserver-3.5.0\apache-tomcat\bin>startup
Using CATALINA_BASE:   C:\Program Files\jasperserver-3.5.0\apache-tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   C:\Program Files\jasperserver-3.5.0\apache-tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: C:\Program Files\jasperserver-3.5.0\apache-tomcat\temp
Using JRE_HOME:        C:\PROGRA~1\JASPER~1.0\java\jre
```

The tomcat window pops up for a split of a second and goes away.

(I have another java instance installed under c:\program files)

Help!!!

**Update:**

Logs from catalina file

```
Mar 22, 2011 3:41:50 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Mar 22, 2011 3:41:50 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1017 ms
Mar 22, 2011 3:41:51 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 22, 2011 3:41:51 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/5.5.20
Mar 22, 2011 3:41:51 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost start
INFO: XML validation disabled
Mar 22, 2011 3:42:06 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Mar 22, 2011 3:42:06 AM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Mar 22, 2011 3:42:06 AM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/43  config=null
Mar 22, 2011 3:42:06 AM org.apache.catalina.storeconfig.StoreLoader load
INFO: Find registry server-registry.xml at classpath resource
Mar 22, 2011 3:42:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 15374 ms
```

Comment: My guess is that your server is actually running, try accessing `localhost:8080`. Probably the Tomcat console does not appear on the screen for some reason, but the server is completely fine.

Comment: thats what it seems to be.... but i tried to run the localhost:8080 and its not running

Comment: This usefull question has been viewed about 14k times ...

Comment: Please, @tecman, if you found the solution by yourself, answer yourself on this question and accept the answer. It will help all the people who will come to look here for the solution. I am writing this because I saw your comment at ykaganovich's answer about how your solved it. Thank you

Answer (score 28):

Use `catalina.bat run` instead of `startup.bat`. Then the window won't go away and you can see what's going on

Comment: it didnt helped either........... finally uninstalled jasperserver, java and reinstalled jasperserver....... its working fine now....

Answer (score 5):

In my case that was a problem with final slash in `%CATALINA_HOME%` path: final slash *should not* be there!

`C:\tomcat\8.0.30` - correct

`C:\tomcat\8.0.30\` - wrong

See http://blackandwhitecomputer.blogspot.de/2015/09/tomcat-debug-cannot-startup.html

Honestly, I had not expected modern applications may be depended on final slash in environment variable path!

Comment: Thank you - I had the same problem, your comment saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar problem. I open cmd prompt and cd to tomcat\bin\startup.bat. The issue was my JRE_HOME not defined in the environment variables. I added and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved it this way:

First, following @ykaganovich suggestions, I tried to start the server using the catalina.bat start command; it did not solve the problem, but at least it showed a log that specified the error, which was really helpful.

In my case, the log said that the problem was because of the java versión. I had the JAVA_HOME variable pointing to the JDK7, but my tomcat version needed it to point to the JDK8.

I changed the JAVA_HOME variable to point to JDK8 (instead of JDK7) and then , when I executed the catalina.bat start command again, it worked perfectly and the server started. I hope my suggestion could be helpful to someone.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm it's very strange problem because in the log you have that server started, so try this:

- restart computer :) - the best solution for strange situations
- change tomcat port
- close every unnecessary applications: skype, ip phones etc (I've encountered similar problem someday and application ip phone "softly" blocked this port ("softly" - in tomcat log everything was OK but in reality webapp doesn't work)

Comment: thanks........finally uninstalled jasperserver, java and reinstalled jasperserver....... its working fine now....

Comment: nice :) so probably you modified some important files

Answer (score 1):

Add tomcat in your eclipse and start it from there. Configure tomcat as 'Use Tomcat installation'. It will work

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem with apache Tomcat 9 version.

Solution very simple.

Apache Tomcat 9 is supported by Java 8 and later versions.
So, i had **JRE_HOME** with **JRE7** path, I binded it to new **JRE8** and everything works fine.

*Different versions of Apache Tomcat are available for different versions of the Servlet and JSP specifications. The mapping between the specifications and the respective Apache Tomcat versions is:*

[image]

Hope this will work for you guys, cheers!

Comment: Please share the link where you did the screen

Answer (score 0):

If Tomcat was earlier working fine and Tomcat not starting happens unexpectedly, it's because some other process has started using the port you were using Tomcat on. In my case, I had shutdown Tomcat and was trying to run my servlet directly from Eclipse. So Eclipse took control of the port. After I closed Eclipse and tried restarting Tomcat (with startup.bat), everything worked fine.

ykaganovich's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5399429/453673) helped me track down my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Non of the solutions above worked for me.

I found my way out by removing my current tomcat and replace it with a new one and setting up again my workspace.

I hope this may help someone

Answer (score 0):

Open up the Tomcat users file (tomcat-users.xml)and check that you've closed all your speech marks. That is what fixed it for me.

Now double-check the role names:

```
<tomcat-users>
<role rolename="admin" />
<role rolename="manager" />
<user username="admin" password="secret" roles="admin,manager" />
</tomcat-users>
```

Finally, execute startup.bat file from bin

Answer (score 0):

The latest versions of Tomcat work with Java (and probably JDE) versions later than 8. I have defined different environment variables JRE_HOME and JAVA_HOME.

- JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20
- JRE_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jre-1.8

In this form, tomcat was launched in bash, but it did not appear in the service list.
[this path to JRE_HOME worked without any problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lu8CV.png)

Everything was solved by changing the path to JRE_HOME. The path to JAVA_HOME is able to replace the path to the JRE. This is because tomcat searches for java_home OR jre_home when it starts.

I also recommend adding JAVA_HOME to the system environment variables

Answer (score -1):

Try to open Tomcat7w.exe or follow the below steps.

(I have installed Tomcat under folder C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0)

1. open command prompt as Administrator
2. run --> "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin\Tomcat7w.exe" //MS//
3. now you can see icon in the system tray
4. double click on icon and start/stop