# Tomcat won't start, no error provided (Windows 7)

Tags: tomcat, batch-file, catalina

I've got a fresh installation of Tomcat 7.0.56. When I run startup.bat (As administrator or not), I got the following message:

```
    Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\uPortal_test\apache-tomcat-7.0.56"
    Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\uPortal_test\apache-tomcat-7.0.56"
    Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\uPortal_test\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\temp"
    Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_71"
    Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\uPortal_test\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\bin\bootstrap.jar;C
    :\uPortal_test\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
```

And that's it. The console closes instantly.
I followed this [Tutorial](https://www.unicon.net/content/build-install-run-uportal-41)

I set CATALINA_HOME at the beginning of startup.bat, just in case, but it should not be necessary

Comment: C:\uPortal_test\apache-tomcat-7.0.56 does this exists?

Comment: Yes, I've binded CATALINA_HOME by copying the address from file explorer.

Comment: Could it be a 64b-32b compatibility issue somewhere?

Comment: if you do click on windows button -> type cmd -> cd C:\uPortal_test\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\bin; startup.bat what's the output you see?

Comment: Written as you suggested, it tell that the specified path is not found. If I only execute cd C:\... in one command, and in a second I try startup.bat, I get the same output as with the batch file, described above.

Comment: so C:\uPortal_test\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\bin does not exists and that's the reason. now do this: click on windows button -> type cmd -> c: - > cd \ -> dir and paste the output basically you yourself can check if that folder exists and if you setted catalina_home correctly

Comment: It exists, actually. If I perform 'dir' while in C:\uPortal_test\apache-tomcat-7.0.56, it shows me that there is a folder called 'bin'. Then if I type -> cd bin and -> dir, I can see shutdown.bat file.

Comment: And the output I've mentionned in the question is generated by startup.bat, so execution actually works. But not completely.

Comment: Ok, that was a problem of memory allocation for JVM. My Xmx was set to 1024m, I've tried 64 and it worked. Thanj you for your time!

Comment: Ok i have made it as an answer so it would help others in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok you need to get the error from command prompt. You will need to do the following:

```
click on windows button 
type cmd (followed by enter)
cd C:\uPortal_test\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\bin (followed by enter)
startup.bat (followed by enter)
```

If you run this batch file you some of the error will pop off the script which will give you hint what wrong you are doing and you can correct accordingly.

Comment: This usually works for me but not this time. See what @ykaganovich suggested https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398654/tomcat-not-starting. It worked for me

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the error did not show up in the command prompt. This can happen if a config file (in my case, setenv.bat) has a syntax error. I was able to isolate the problem by adding **rem** in front of each setting line in the bat file to isolate the root cause.

I was missing double quotes around a file path that included spaces.

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djuli-logback.configurationFile=%CATALINA_HOME%\conf\logback.xml
```

Should have been:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djuli-logback.configurationFile="%CATALINA_HOME%\conf\logback.xml"
```