# Starting Tomcat with CMD

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm trying to automatically start and stop tomcat 8.0. I've got the stop to work. When I try and start it, it runs in the command line (but still shows Stopped as in the img below) and everything works fine but as soon as I close the window it shuts down. Does anyone know how I can start tomcat as I would by clicking on the Start button?

[image: Tomcat Stopped]

Comment: There is a log directory in `c:\program files\apache software foundation\Tomcat 8.0`, can you take a look at the file named `catalina.out` and post what's inside?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398654/tomcat-not-starting?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is installed as a service with name `Tomcat8` this command should start it when called with admin rights.

```
net start Tomcat8
```